# How to put text in the middle in OpenOffice?

Tags: openoffice

How can we vertically set a text to the middle of an empty page in OpenOffice 4.1?

Comment: Can you clarify?  Which OO application?  What do you mean by vertically set text?  What do you mean by the middle of the page (an empty page with just the text, mixed with other text, how should the other text flow in relation, etc.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the text into a vertically-centered frame (menu `Insert` -> `Frame`):

[image]

Make sure to put the frame vertically centered to the **entire page** - otherwise it won't be absolutely centered if you have different values for top/bottom margins.

*EDIT: this works for LibreOffice Writer - i assume it works with OpenOffice, too, but i didn't test it.*